# Express not reading request

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to write an app that logs in and authenticates an individual. I already have another app called "doctors" which I have used the Mongoose, Passport, and Passport-Local modules and the app works fine.

I have tried to copy and paste that code to my new app and start a new database, and it isn't working. I would like someone to point out the error of my ways. What must I do first, or what must I do differently?

When I try to log in, this is what I receive in the console:

```
{ username: 'Chips', password: 'Salsa' }
Searching....
```

It never breaks due to failure or timing out. This is my login module:

```
var express = require('express');
var connection = require('../mySQLConnection');
var router = express.Router();
var Q = require('q');
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

router.route('/')
    .post(function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log("Searching....");
        var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user){
            if(err){
                console.log('An error');
                return next(err);
            } else if (!user){
                res.send({ success: false });
                console.log('This is false');
            } else {
                req.logIn(user, function(err){
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    res.send({ success:true, user: user  });
                    console.log("Login worked");
                });
            }
        });

    });

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the server.js in the root folder.

```
var login = require('./server/routes/login');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

if(app.get('env') === 'development') {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tasks');
} else {
    console.log('production');
}   

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error...'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('db opened');
});

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.find({}).exec(function(err, collection){
    if (collection.length === 0) {
        User.create({username:'Chips', password:'Salsa'});
    }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({username:username}).exec(function(err, user) {
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
                console.log("This works");
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
                console.log("Nothing is found");
            }
        });
    }
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    if(user) {
        done(null, user._id);
    } 
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({_id:id}).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
});

app.use('/api/login', login);
```

The only difference is the code is this part. Note I'm not using this for production

```
if(app.get('env') === 'development') {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tasks');
} else {
    console.log('production');
}
```

In the original app that works, the code is

```
if(app.get('env') === 'development') {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/doctors');
} else {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://<user>:<password>/doctors');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that changing `var router = express.Router();` to `var app = express();` and changing `router.route` to `app.route` and adding the module body-parser made me able to process requests. I had both app = express() and body-parser on the root server.js file, but not the login route file. As I noob I learn something new every day.